# Working with NSFetched result controller and sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am new to core data and NSFetched resultcontroller. So far I managed to fill up my tableView. But now I want to divided into sections. Here is how my code looks like.

```
- (void)getKeepers // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Team"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES]];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

}
```

Let me sketch the situation. I am making an app for a football club. In my tableview I want for every position (goalkeeper,defender,winger,attacker) a new section. My core database looks like this.

```
- TEAM
   -name
   -Position
   -img_url
   -birthDate
   -sortOrder
```

I added the attribute sortOrder to sort my players. But can anybody help me to divide it into sections?

Thanks in advance !!

**WHAT I DO IN MY CELL_FOR_ROW_AT_INDEX**
In my cellForRowAtIndex I am doing not the usual thing. I am working with a custom tableviewCell which contains 6 imageviews. But its possible that a row only contains 4 images. You can see what I am trying to do over [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8050170687/).

```
#define IMAGES_PER_ROW  6

   NSInteger frcRow = indexPath.row * IMAGES_PER_ROW; // row in fetched results controller

    for (int col = 1; col <= IMAGES_PER_ROW; col++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:frcRow inSection:0];
        Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
        NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
        UIImage *image;
        if (imgData == nil) {
            // default image
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"keeperNil.jpg"];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        }
        [cell setImage:image forPosition:col];
        frcRow ++;
    }
```

Comment: You should start by giving a key path as `sectionNameKeyPath:`, i.e. `sectionNameKeyPath:@"Position"`. Then you need the plain boilerplate routines for the various `UITableViewDataSource` methods, to actually see the sections in the table view.

Comment: What do you mean with plain boilerplate routines ?

Comment: You should really look for a new way to load your images.  Doing it that way will block the UI while each image downloads.  You should be downloading the images asynchronously and saving them somewhere.  Then displaying them from wherever they are saved (an array or something).  Also not quite sure what you're doing with the custom path.

Comment: The stuff you get when you start a project with the right project template in XCode, using Core Data. They are also given on the apple developer site. And in the answer below by Fogmeister.

Comment: I tried a dozen of other things to show these pictures like that on screen. But this is the only way I got it almost right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sectionNameKeyPath` value to be the field you want to use for the sections.

Then you need these three functions...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];

    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

This should be enough.

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath function should look something like this...

```
...
UITableViewCell* cell = [UITableViewCell dequeueCellWithReuseIdnetifier:@"blah"];

Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = team.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = team.position.
```

Or something like that.

The error you are getting means you are trying to access an array that doesn't contain enough entries.

If that doesn't work then post your cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got the following error: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 5 in section at index 0'

Comment: Sounds like your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath function isn't working right.  Will edit answer to show a template function...

Comment: I've edited my code with my CellForRowAtIndex. I am working with a customCell with 6 imageviews in it.